# VSTS (Visual Studio Team System) build will not finish

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-pipelines

I created a build for my C# WebAPI solution with just the default build tests, mostly build and run unit tests.  All of the various steps are completed (green check box), but the build still says in progress and has a cancel button and will not finish. Why?

[image: alldone]
[image: inprogress]

Comment: It finally finished. All of the logs are for less than a minute (2:16pm), but the build did not get marked as completed until 2:26pm. And this is only a tiny webapi project that builds locally in a few seconds.

Comment: Looks like a glitch in the system. Unless its happening consistently I would not worry... If you run the build again does it complete?

Comment: There was a performance degradation that caused the problem. Should be ok now. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=13385

Comment: I'd rather close/delete this question as there is no real solution and the problem was temporary and out of the sphere of influence of the Q to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this was a temporary performance degradation issue with VSTS.  Thanks @jessehouwing!